# Android to Android communication through internet

Tags: android, client

I know the basics of programming java, c(++), sql etc. Now I want to step it up with a specific application that combines arduino hardware with android. The communication I need would be similar to that of "Fundawear" (google it). I need a constant stream of simple data (integers probably) between two android devices that are connected to the internet but not in the same LAN. Then this data will be sent to a bluetooth module over a serial connection.

I've sought through a lot of websites about android server-client apps but I still haven't found a clear answer as to which type of connection of server and which classes would work best for me. Once I know this I'll probably manage to self-teach the rest.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Getting downvoted on a question where I ask for some direction is very demotivating for a hobbyist who is interested in learning more!

Answer (score 0):

Getting inter-device stuff working reliably can be quite challenging; there always seems to be one more edge-case that needs to be resolved. Rather than rebuilding the wheel, I recommend using an existing library where someone else has already worked out all the kinks. I haven't used it yet, but the [AllJoyn open-source project](https://allseenalliance.org/developer-resources/alljoyn-open-source-project) looks very promising.

For cross-LAN connectivity, you might be able to leverage the real-time multiplayer aspects of [Google Play Game Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am definately planning on using an existing library, the issue is that I have no idea which one fits my needs. The problem with AllJoyn is that the devices have to be using a common network. I'm not too worried about controlling the Arduino with an Android device as I have done this before. My main concern here is the communication over internet between two remote Android devices (not in the same network).

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. For connecting multiple devices, there will need to be something acting as an addressable server. That could be one of your devices, but that would require local router configuration. The standard alternative is to have a standard server that functions as a gateway between devices. You might be able to leverage the Google Play Game Services for your needs. I updated my answer with a link to the latter.

Comment: The messaging between players in GPGS seems to be exactly what I need at first glance. I'll keep you posted on my progress, thanks so much!